# Add TapGestureRecognizer on platform specific

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is it possible to add a `TapGestureRecognizer` on only UWP? Something like this

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="GestureRecognizers">
    <OnPlatform.Platforms>
        <On Platform="UWP">
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding MyUWPCommand}"/>
        </On>
    </OnPlatform.Platforms>
</OnPlatform>
```

Comment: Do you have to do this in Xaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XAML:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Label">
    <On Platform="UWP">
        <Label Text="TapGestureRecognizer for UWP">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding MyUWPCommand}" />
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
    </On>
    <On Platform="Android, iOS">
        <Label Text="No GestureRecognizers for Android, iOS" />
    </On>
</OnPlatform>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just in the code of the `MyUWPCommand` check if the current platform is UWP? If so, execute the code, if not, do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Just have to wrap each GestureRecognizer in an OnPlatform

```
<ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
  <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="GestureRecognizer">
    <OnPlatform.Platforms>
        <On Platform="UWP">
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding MyUWPCommand}"/>
        </On>
    </OnPlatform.Platforms>
  </OnPlatform>
</ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
```